# Java JDBC - No suitable Driver found

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I've got a problem with my code accessing a local database. I am using Eclipse and postgresql.

I am well aware that there are already several posts like that but they didn't help me on my problem so that is why I am asking myself.

The jar file for the drivers is already in the library and is also added to the Build Path. However I am still getting the error from the Driver not being found.

> Can't get a connection: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for psql -h localhost beleg postgres

My code looks like this:

```
package DB;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connections {

private Connection dbcon;
private Statement stmt;
private Statement stmt2;

Connections(String db_url, String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);

        stmt = dbcon.createStatement();
        stmt2 = dbcon.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Can't get a connection: " + e.toString());

        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException f) {
        }

        try {
            if (stmt2 != null)
                stmt2.close();
        } catch (SQLException f) {
        }
        try {
            if (dbcon != null)
                dbcon.close();
        } catch (SQLException f) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

[image: added the JAR with Add Jar, since it is in the lib folder of the project..]

Comment: What's the value of `db_url`?

Comment: "psql -h localhost beleg postgres"

Comment: The error tells you that the URL syntax is wrong.  Needs to look like this: jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database.  Refer to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html

Comment: Side note: If you're using a JDBC 4.0+ compatible driver, the `Class.forName` call is no longer needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JDBC URL is invalid. Try changing it to:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/<database name>
```

See the [PostgreSQL JDBC docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) for more information.

Comment: Oh yeah I see my mistake now. I did copy the url which I write into the console to access my database.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your URL correct, please consider rethinking your class design.  `java.sql.Statement` is *not* thread safe.  It should never, ever be a shared private member variable.

You should create `Statement` and `ResultSet` in method scope, use them, and close them before exiting the method.

You should be pooling database connections.

Database access has been solved for a long time in Java.  If you don't use Spring Boot, I would recommend looking at their `JdbcTemplate` implementation to see how it could be done with minimal boilerplate.